# Getting the poll result from send_poll telegram bot with python

Tags: python, telegram-bot

It's a python code for a telegram bot to take a poll from the group chat. How can I get the final result of send_poll bot? I know the bot shows the result in the chat group but I need to save and use it for later. 
For example, here I need the output to be like a or b.

```
    def poll(bot, update):
        options=['a','b']  
        bot.send_poll(update.message.chat_id, "please choose option a or 
        b:",options)
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('set', poll))  
    updater.start_polling()
```

[The following picture shows the output of send_poll bot in the group chat. I like to have the answer which here is 'b', not only in the group chat also as a returned answer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuLcI.png)

Comment: could you explain a bit more and provide code?

Comment: I just added code and more explanation.

Comment: I don't think it's possible yet, but check the incoming updates for vote results. Maybe Telegram sends vote result inside message object's poll property when a user votes for an option.

Comment: It would be nice if there was a minimum working example. As it is, the question is incomplete and not very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

the response provided to your handler is something like:

```
{'update_id': 696992167, 
  'poll': {
    'id': '5920521737891479577', 
    'question': 'What is the capital of Ukraine?', 
    'options': [
      {'text': 'Rabat', 'voter_count': 0}, 
      {'text': 'Kyiv', 'voter_count': 1}, 
      {'text': 'Luxembourg', 'voter_count': 0}], 
    'total_voter_count': 1, 'is_closed': False, 'is_anonymous': True, 
    'type': 'quiz', 'allows_multiple_answers': False, 
    'correct_option_id': 1, 'explanation_entities': [], 'close_date': None}}
```

Notice the options are the answer you provided and `voter_count=1` tells you the one picked by the user.

You can then process the request and use/save the value as you need

```
def get_answer(update):
answers = update.poll.options

ret = ""

for answer in answers:
    if answer.voter_count == 1:
        ret = answer.text

return ret
```

In order to implement the quiz you need to define how to send a question and how to process the answer:

```
# send question
context.bot.send_poll(chat_id=xxx, question='The question?',
                                options=[], type=Poll.QUIZ, correct_option_id=n, is_anonymous=True)

# define method 'main_handler' to process the answer
updater.dispatcher.add_handler(PollHandler(main_handler, pass_chat_data=True, pass_user_data=True))
```

Comment: Hi Beppe, that I think totally works, but how do you get that response? Because there's not a function like getPoll, there's only sendPoll so how do you get "the update"? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Dani, I have expanded the answer, hope it helps.

Comment: Hi Beppe, I have a similar problem in the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66360862/how-to-identify-the-user-answer-from-a-quiz-using-python-telegram-bot-module?noredirect=1#comment117343476_66360862 , but when I click in the answer in the chat group, the voter_count doesn't change. I tried to use telegram.PollAnswer but it doesn't seem to work. Thanks in advance.