# How to identify the user answer from a quiz using the python-telegram-bot library

Tags: telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to write a Python code so that I can apply a questionnaire to my physics students remotely. They would receive and reply to the quiz via
a Telegram bot. I'm using the python-telegram-bot module. I can already identify which users replied, but I can't get yet their answers.

I am starting with the example code pollbot.py from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/master/examples/pollbot.py

The specific methods are these:

```
def quiz(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Send a predefined poll"""
    questions = ["1", "2", "4", "20"]
    message = update.effective_message.reply_poll(
        "How many eggs do you need for a cake?", questions, type=Poll.QUIZ, correct_option_id=2
    )
    # Save some info about the poll the bot_data for later use in receive_quiz_answer
    payload = {
        message.poll.id: {"chat_id": update.effective_chat.id, "message_id": message.message_id}
    }
    context.bot_data.update(payload)

def receive_quiz_answer(update: Update, context: CallbackContext) -> None:
    """Close quiz after three participants took it"""
    # the bot can receive closed poll updates we don't care about
    if update.poll.is_closed:
        return
    if update.poll.total_voter_count == 3:
        try:
            quiz_data = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]
        # this means this poll answer update is from an old poll, we can't stop it then
        except KeyError:
            return
        context.bot.stop_poll(quiz_data["chat_id"], quiz_data["message_id"])
```

The telegram app shows to the user if s/he answered correctly or not. I already know which user answered the quiz. I would like to know programmatically which of the possible options of the quiz the user answered.

I did print message in the quiz method and I found this:

{'message_id': 93, 'date': 1614250320, 'chat': {'id': xxxxxxxx, 'type': 'private', 'first_name': 'user', 'last_name': 'name'}, 'entities': [], 'caption_entities': [], 'photo': [], 'new_chat_members': [], 'new_chat_photo': [], 'delete_chat_photo': False, 'group_chat_created': False, 'supergroup_chat_created': False, 'channel_chat_created': False, 'poll': {'id': '5024004102909067266', 'question': 'How many eggs do you need for a cake?', 'options': [{'text': '1', 'voter_count': 0}, {'text': '2', 'voter_count': 0}, {'text': '4', 'voter_count': 0}, {'text': '20', 'voter_count': 0}], 'total_voter_count': 0, 'is_closed': False, 'is_anonymous': True, 'type': 'quiz', 'allows_multiple_answers': False, 'correct_option_id': 2, 'explanation_entities': [], 'close_date': None}, 'from': {'id': 144******6, 'first_name': '*my_own*', 'is_bot': True, 'username': '_my_own_Bot'}}

It seems the info on the user answer is nowhere here.
Also voter_count is not changing, it stays at zero no matter how many
answers I click on at the chat group.
I added these lines in the method receive_quiz_answer:

```
 quiz_data = context.bot_data[update.poll.id]
 print(quiz_data)
```

and I only got this info:

{'chat_id': 15******53, 'message_id': 87}

which is not relevant for what I want. I believe the answer should be in
telegram.PollAnswer, which is not listed in the code above.

I added the following lines:

```
answer = update.poll_answer
print("answer is {}". format(answer))
```

in receive_quiz_answer method, but I got the reply:

answer is None

Any help appreciated.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lack of details in my question. I did add the few lines of code

Comment: Much better.  Printing the return value is just what you needed to do next.  That output shows that this is an issue with the specific API, not Python -- it's not a Stack Overflow issue.  You need to solve this through the bot documentation and message boards; SO is not a general support desk.

Comment: I just removed python from the list of topics. But there is a group here in SO called python-telegram-bot. Why this question is not suitable for it?

Comment: You're asking for support on how to use a particular bot, rather than on how to use the package in general.  You might update your question to describe that the bot does not return the answers.  Then do your best to update the code to add that capability, and ask for help with that upgrade.

Comment: The correct answer should be indeed in the payload you receive, for example ` {'text': '2', 'voter_count': 1}` if 2 was the right answer, and 'total_voter_count' should be 1. I dont see anything wrong in the code you posted, maybe check the version you are using

Comment: In `reply_poll` I set a timeout (5) but it shouldnt make a difference (it does not actually show any countdown to the user anyway)

Comment: Thanks a lot.  My python-telegram-bot version is 13.0 and the Python version is 3.6.9

Comment: Sorry I accidentally posted my comment before I finished writing.  My earlier version of python-telegram-bot was 13.0 and now I upgraded to the latest one 13.3. My Python version is 3.6.9. The problem persisted. This then  might be a bug in python-telegram-bot. I'll try to see if I get the voter_count in the poll method.